# Mahapps Floating Watermark Font Size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using Mahapps and declaring it in the XAML as follows:

```
xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

the floating watermark using the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.TextButton" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.IsWaitingForData" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
</Style>
```

I declare and use a TextBox as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSomeText" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Some Text"/>
```

My issue is that when the floating watermark appears it is in a 10 point font as defined in FloatingWatermarkFontSize in Controls.TextBox.xaml.  I can override the text size by putting this in the UserControl's ResourceDictionary:

```
<System:Double x:Key="FloatingWatermarkFontSize">16</System:Double>
```

However, while that changes the size of the font, the area for the floating watermark is only large enough to accommodate that 10 point text.  Is there any way to more effectively change the font size of the floating watermark?

Comment: did u find any solution for it ?

Comment: The best I could come up with was to add a LayoutTransform.  It made both the text and the watermark text larger, but my real goal was to get the watermark legible for our users, it worked in that sense.  Our controls were in a Stackpanel, so it was applied like this:

        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
    ...
    </StackPanel>

Comment: I'm unsure if the codebase has changed since this question was asked, but the method you tried by putting the "FloatingWatermarkFontSize" works fairly well for me assuming the size of the TextBox can accommodate the watermark font size and text font size at the same time. Im using 124px tall text box and that can easily fit a size 25 floating watermark and size 45 text. Thanks for finding that trick :)